# The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty in LexPredict setup

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, secret-key

I am using ubuntu 16.04 to setup LexPredict (https://github.com/LexPredict/lexpredict-contraxsuite) and the deployment setup (https://github.com/LexPredict/lexpredict-contraxsuite-deploy).

I have followed all the steps of "Local Machine Installation" mentioned in the deployment document, but I am getting the following error:

```
 django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty
```

after executing the following command:

```
./setup_local.sh | tee -a log.txt
```

I have generated a key online for django from http://www.miniwebtool.com/django-secret-key-generator/ then input in the /opt/lexpredict-contraxsuite/contraxsuite_services/settings.py as

```
SECRET_KEY = "yj6o@&vrar6^l1u68!bxugj@xr4&5)zzk!h1qw&13^&@2d3wp#"
```

and also in /opt/lexpredict-contraxsuite-deploy/local/local_settings.py files.

but still, I am getting the same error.
django version 1.11.3

stack trace:

```
    [localhost] out: Traceback (most recent call last):
    [localhost] out:   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 184, in _run_module_as_main
    [localhost] out:     "__main__", mod_spec)
    [localhost] out:   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    [localhost] out:     exec(code, run_globals)
    [localhost] out:   File "/opt/ve/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/__main__.py", line 18, in <module>
    [localhost] out:     main()
    [localhost] out:   File "/opt/ve/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/__main__.py", line 14, in main
    [localhost] out:     _main()
    [localhost] out:   File "/opt/ve/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 326, in main
    [localhost] out:     cmd.execute_from_commandline(argv)
    [localhost] out:   File "/opt/ve/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 488, in execute_from_commandline
    [localhost] out:     super(CeleryCommand, self).execute_from_commandline(argv)))
    [localhost] out:   File "/opt/ve/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 279, in execute_from_commandline
    [localhost] out:     argv = self.setup_app_from_commandline(argv)
    [localhost] out:   File "/opt/ve/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 481, in setup_app_from_commandline
    [localhost] out:     self.app = self.find_app(app)
    [localhost] out:   File "/opt/ve/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 503, in find_app
    [localhost] out:     return find_app(app, symbol_by_name=self.symbol_by_name)
    [localhost] out:   File "/opt/ve/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/app/utils.py", line 374, in find_app
    [localhost] out:     symbol_by_name=symbol_by_name, imp=imp,
    [localhost] out:   File "/opt/ve/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/app/utils.py", line 358, in find_app
    [localhost] out:     sym = imp(app)
    [localhost] out:   File "/opt/ve/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/utils/imports.py", line 101, in import_from_cwd
    [localhost] out:     return imp(module, package=package)
    [localhost] out:   File "/opt/ve/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    [localhost] out:     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    [localhost] out:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
    [localhost] out:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
    [localhost] out:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    [localhost] out:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
    [localhost] out:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
    [localhost] out:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
    [localhost] out:   File "/opt/lexpredict-contraxsuite/contraxsuite_services/apps/celery.py", line 45, in <module>
    [localhost] out:     django.setup()
    [localhost] out:   File "/opt/ve/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 22, in setup
    [localhost] out:     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
    [localhost] out:   File "/opt/ve/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    [localhost] out:     self._setup(name)
    [localhost] out:   File "/opt/ve/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    [localhost] out:     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
    [localhost] out:   File "/opt/ve/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 129, in __init__
    [localhost] out:     raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
    [localhost] out: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
    [localhost] out:    > celery2@osboxes: * Child terminated with exit code 1
    [localhost] out: FAILED 
    [localhost] out:
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like you don't tell django which settings to use.

You can explicitly tell django to use your settings via enviroment variable

```
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=<yourmodule>.settings
```

Or as parameter of manage.py:

```
--settings=<yourmodule>.settings
```

Comment: I have updated in manage.py as 
    **DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=contraxsuite_services.settings**
but still, it shows the same error. I have also updated the wsgi.py but after that also it shows the same error.

Comment: include content of your setup_local.sh script to understand how you start your django app

Comment: Here it is the content of setup_local.sh
https://github.com/LexPredict/lexpredict-contraxsuite-deploy/blob/master/setup_local.sh

Comment: hm.sorry i dont know how fabric works. You just need to make sure that django picks up your settings. You can try settings environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE in env where you start you app.